# How to get record with particular date as local timezone in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
WHERE (e.send_date ::date = '2024-02-04')
```

I am fetching records where send_date 2024-02-04 but in some record when I convert time to local timezone its giving date 2024-02-05 in some record.

How can I fix that problem in my query?

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. Without the column types and example data to demonstrate the issue, we can only guess at what the actual issue is. I suspect that the issue is due to inadequate consideration of time zones, but you haven't provided enough information to offer more specific guidance.